# PodSixNet: can't make connection from different computers

Tags: python, networking

I made a simple multiplayer chat with python and PodSixNet, and it works perfectly when I run it on different terminals on my computer. But when I'm trying to connect to the same chat from different computer, I permanently get disconnected. What could I be doing wrong?
I run the server on 0.0.0.0:8000 and the clients on localhost:8000 (though tried localhost on both and 0.0.0.0 on both. still nothing). The computers are connected to the same wi-fi.

Comment: Looks like you're telling the clients to try to connect to themselves, rather than the server.

Comment: but why does this work from terminals on the same computer then?

Comment: Connecting the client to "localhost" means "connect to the computer I'm on". That will only work when the client and server are on the same machine.

Comment: okay. so how do I choose the address to use?

Comment: where can I read more about it? I'm just not really sure what exactly to google.

Comment: When trying to connect via another machine, input the local ip of your server and the port instead of `0.0.0.0:8000` . For exemple : `<server-local-ip>:8000`

Comment: but how do I know on which ip to run the server? by the server here I  mean another python file which can listen and send data etc

Comment: Run your code on your main laptop (the server should be accessible @ `0.0.0.0:8000`). From the same laptop type `ifconfig` in terminal to retrieve your local IP address (`en0` / `inet` if you are connected via wifi). Then from another laptop type in `<inet>:8000` to access the server.

Comment: yeah it works. now i understand why. thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me. Took Ip and port number of the server from the user in client program(Ip and port number of the server to which the client wants to connect to).

In server code, pass IP and port number of the server itself when making object of server class in main function

`address, port = raw_input("Host:Port (localhost:8000): ")
    if not address:
        host, port = "localhost", 8000
    else:
        host, port = address.split(":")
    s = GameServer(localaddr=(host, int(port)))`

In Client, replace 
`self.Connect()` with

`address = raw_input('Address of server: ')
        try:
            if not address:
                host, port = "localhost", 8000
            else:
                host, port = address.split(":")
            self.Connect((host, int(port)))
        except:
            print("Error Connecting to server")
            exit()`

Hope this helps.